# database.com nodes different from force.com?

Tags: api, rest-api, database.com

In Salesforce orgs we have nodes based closeness from geographic locations, like if I register for org from India it will put me on Asia-Pacific(ex. AP1), same happens for other locations like North America (NA1, NA9 etc).

I am curious about database.com, as its nodes are having very different naming convention, for ex:

```
https://flow-app-6104.database.com
```

Because of this, I am not too sure about closeness of a given node to a geographic location. Would it make difference from network latency standpoint in API calls, if my mobile app will access database.com APIs across the world, for ex. some one in India, UK and US etc.

Comment: I wouldn't think so coz users worldwide use our emea production org without complaining about any significant network latency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database.com uses the same infrastructure as the rest of Salesforce.com. The URLs are tailored for the Database.com product, but the orgs are still located in the same place as the Salesforce.com orgs.

To find which node your db.com org is on, start with the host name. For instance mine is:

```
https://velocity-inspiration-8052.database.com
```

Go to the [trust web site's system status page](http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/status/) and look for the "What instance am I using" link in the upper right corner. Click on that.

In the "My Domain Lookup" pop-up, enter in only the third-level domain information off of your Database.com org URL. For instance mine would be:

```
velocity-inspiration-8052
```

Once I have that entered in, I get back EU2. Presumably, if you were to register for an org in the AP region, you would find yourself on an AP node...but as stated in the comments, not necessarily.

Comment: Perfect, this answers the question @Peter